# sql construct condition with if statement mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I want to construct such sql condition. I have a table car, it has such fields `id_status`, `id_category` and `storage_address`. I need to select cars which are `id_status` in (2,4) and if `id_category = 4` I need to check field `storage_address` to be not null or empty. How could I make it? should I use sql `if` statement?
I need something like:

```
select * from car where id_status in (2,4) and if(id_category =
4,storage_address is NOT NULL,'1=1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM car
WHERE id_status in (2,4)
AND IF(
  id_category = 4,
  storage_address IS NOT NULL,
  1
)
```

Simply put, you do not need the string `'1=1'`, just a plain `1` will do as a truthy value.

Or you can just do

```
SELECT *
FROM car
WHERE id_status in (2, 4)
AND (
  id_category != 4
  OR storage_address IS NOT NULL
)
```